# Access sql query reads the ID from the form but doesn't update when the query runs for the next record

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access, I populate a listbox with a sql query that reads the ID from the form to pull data from another table. When moving to the next record the listbox doesn't update for the new ID from the next record. It works when I run the query by itself.

In the form, I run it on the Form Current event, but it only uses the first ID from the first display record.

In the form current I use `DoCmd.OpenQuery "sqlNotes"` to run the query.

```
SELECT tblNotes.note_date AS [Entry], tblNotes.author AS [Author], tblNotes.note_text AS [Comment], tblNotes.percent AS [%], tblNotes.note_id 
FROM tblNotes
WHERE tblNotes.note_id=[Forms]![frmTasks]![ID]
ORDER BY tblNotes.note_date;
```

Comment: Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Better would be **Pct**.

Answer (score 0):

In the form current, instead of re-running the query directly, I had to update the listbox by re-querying it.

```
Me.ListBox.Requery
```

Comment: Nowhere is listbox mentioned in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, requery of listbox (or combobox) would be required.